# Placing Shiny render outputs inside other functions

Tags: r, shiny

So I am making a shiny app that takes multiple inputs and produces multiple plots and tables of those inputs.

Sample RenderTable code to make one table is below:

```
output$Table1 <- 
      renderTable(data.frame(Shape = c("\u25CF", "\u25B2", "\u25FC", ""),
                             "Genes" = c(input$custom_genes1, "Mean"),
                              Analysed_values = c(t(analysis1()), mean(analysis1()))), 
                              striped = TRUE, bordered = TRUE, hover = TRUE)
```

Where Shape is the symbol on the plot, "Genes" are the genes selected using a selectizeInput, and analysis1() is the result of a reactive calculation defined earlier in the code.

However I have 8-9 tables that need to be displayed depending on various checkboxes etc. Rather than copy-pasting the code out and replacing all the relevant values, I wanted to make a function that I could use to quickly display all the tables, and if I needed to change the formatting or add anything later I can just edit the function rather than each table individually.

I tried making a re-usable function using the code below:

```
construct_table <- function(genes_select, dataset){
    renderTable(data.frame(Shape = c("\u25CF", "\u25B2", "\u25FC", ""),
                          "Genes" = genes_select,
                           Analysed_values = c(t(dataset), mean(dataset))), 
                           striped = TRUE, bordered = TRUE, hover = TRUE)
  }
```

And then making it easier to call each table directly:

```
output$Table1 <- construct_table(input$custom_genes1, analysis1())
```

This works in that is creates the table using the initial input values, but doesn't make the table reactive.

How can I call the renderTable reactive function inside a normal function, or is there another reactive function that I have overlooked that I can nest the renderTable function inside of that works the same way as the normal function does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply adding a `output$Table1 <- construct_table(input$custom_genes1, analysis1())` call anywhere will not work because `analysis()` is a reactive variable depending on other inputs the user can change. Hence `analysis()` can be used from a reactive context. ie. from inside `observe, observeEvent, reactive, eventReactive or inside any renderXXX call ex: renderTable, renderPlot...`

When we call `output$Table1 <- construct_table(input$custom_genes1, analysis1())`, 
we are using `analysis1()` from **outside** a reactive context which will cause an error. The solution is Shiny Modules which is specifically designed to modularize code, which seems to be the goal here.

> https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/modules.html

Here is an example,

```
dataset = mtcars

generatePlot = function(input,output,session,data){
  output$plot = renderPlot({
    plot(data()$hp,data()$mpg)
    })
}


generateUI = function(id){
  ns = NS(id)
  plotOutput(ns("plot"))
}

shinyApp(
  ui = {
    fluidPage(
      sliderInput("slider","MPG filter",min(dataset$mpg),max(dataset$mpg),dataset$mpg),
      generateUI("mod1"),
      generateUI("mod2")
    )
  },
  server = function(input,output,session){

    data = eventReactive(input$slider,{
      dataset%>%
        dplyr::filter(between(mpg,input$slider[[1]],input$slider[[2]]))%>%
        return(.)
    })

    callModule(generatePlot,"mod1",data = data)
    callModule(generatePlot,"mod2",data = data)

  }
)
```

You can add many more identical plots by simply adding a new `generateUI` and a new `callModule` call.

Comment: Thanks, sorry for the delayed reply, I believe this is what I was looking for, although I haven't tried ShinyModules before.